# Как найти большое и вывести на экран при помощи условных операторов if else?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте как найти большое и вывести на экран при помощи условных операторов if else

var a = 3;
var b = 4;
var c = 9;

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает встроенная функция языка для нахождения наибольшего?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете написать функцию, подобную этой

```
function max( a, b, c ) {
    var max = a;

    if ( max < b ) max = b;
    if ( max < c ) max = c;

    return max;
}
```

Или

```
function max( a, b, c ) {
    var max;

    if ( a < b ) max = b;
    else max = a;

    if ( max < c ) max = c;

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ неверный, нужно с `if else` :Р

Comment: Он нужен автору вопроса, а не мне.

Comment: @Visman Предложение If - это частный случай if-else